# SQL Database deletion

Tags: sql

Problem:
I updated the wrong table in the database.
Is there any way to get the original database back?

Please help
Thanks

```
UPDATE As SET   Name = 'A',
```

Server: sql server 2005
I have already committed the update statement.

Sorry for not including it earlier.

Comment: Is this SQLServer? Also, have you committed the update statement? (If you haven't, then **don't**!)

Comment: Yes - restore last night's backup and roll forward your twice-hourly log shipping logs. You've got these in place on your production database, right?

Comment: Do you have a backup of your original database?

Comment: What recovery model is your database in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is SQL Server, and you don't have any backups in place then I don't believe so.

SQL Server doesn't automatically do any data backups for you.

However, if you do have a backup stored, you can restore this using SQL Server Management Studio.